# Can't use middle mouse button click to open a link in new tab in Chrome/Chromium

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, chromium

Clicking the middle button (scroll wheel) on a link does't open link in a new tab, like it does on Windows. Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Details:

1. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
2. Chromium Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
3. Generic mouse with two buttons and one scroll wheel

Comment: Does it work in other programs? For example, if you middle-click a folder in your file manager, does it open in a new tab?

Comment: @user3140225 No. Should it?

Comment: If it was a browser issue, middle click should work in other apps. Since it doesn't, it looks like it is a system issue. Can you run `xev` in a terminal and then use middle-click and see if it registers any output?

Comment: wheel click is doesnt work in xev :(